# Draw circles around multiple markers in Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to place circles around multiple markers in Maps API v3

This is what I've done so far:

```
function initialize(){
    var locations = [
      ['Band Stand', 19.04519, 72.819091],
      ['Gateway Of India Mumbai', 18.921984, 72.834654],
      ['Haji Ali', 18.9778192, 72.8104819],
      ['Kings Circle', 19.032261, 72.857225],
    ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-sec'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.0822507,72.8811862),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      radius: 1000,
      fillColor: '#AA0000'
    });
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
      circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

However, this is giving me a circle around only one of the locations. What should I do to get multiple circles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving this:

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 1000,
  fillColor: '#AA0000'
});
```

..inside the for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      radius: 1000,
      fillColor: '#AA0000'
    });
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
  circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    })(marker, i));
}
```